# When i try get the content of iframe using jquery i am getting error.Please help me to solve

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have used the below script to get the `iframe` content, but getting

> **Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'**

```
jQuery("#"+iframe_id).contents().find("#widget-container").html();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not access the contents of a document which is not on the same domain as the parent document. That is the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: It is a widget from third party plugin. Can i access the iframe content ? Please confirm me.

Comment: You can not access it, if the documents source is not from your domain. 3rd party widget highly sounds like this will not be possible.